# Use plotly to plot timeline

Tags: python, charts, timeline, gantt-chart

I can get a timeline graph with plotly with the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data_in = """name,start_time,end_time
event1,2022-01-18T18:34:26.222843,2022-01-18T23:34:26.222843
event1,2022-01-19T10:34:26.222843,2022-01-19T23:34:26.222843
event2,2022-01-20T08:34:26.222843,2022-01-20T11:34:26.222843
event1,2022-01-20T08:34:26.222843,2022-01-20T15:34:26.222843
event2,2022-01-20T12:34:26.222843,2022-01-20T22:34:26.222843
event1,2022-01-21T09:34:26.222843,2022-01-21T23:34:26.222843
event1,2022-01-22T07:34:26.222843,2022-01-22T21:34:26.222843
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_in))
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="start_time", x_end="end_time", y="name", height=200)
fig.show()
```

[image: timeline]

Is it possible to use plotille (https://github.com/tammoippen/plotille) or any other python terminal charting tool to plot something like this?

Comment: This would be easy enough to implement, I imagine, if you just want to visualize something in text. Just iterate through each possible time in your time range, and if it's in an event, print a `|` or something, and if it's not, print a space. You can maybe use the datetime library to check whether dates/times are greater than or less than other dates/times.